# Percentage of Christians to hold pre- or post-tribulation view of rapture

Tags: eschatology, rapture, demographics, tribulation

What percentage of all Christians, who believe in pre-millenial Rapture of the Church hold pre-tribulation, respectively post-tribulation view? As far as I know, majority of Christians hold pre-tribulation view. But can anybody tell the percentage?

Comment: I guess you're not interested in what percentage hold neither view (which globally, and  historically, is probably the vast majority)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Many Evangelicals have long suspected that the largest percentage of Christians overall would support a pre-Tribulation view, an idea that was corroborated by the data, as the largest share of pastors—36 percent—reported believing in that Rapture paradigm. The second largest proportion was the 25 percent who agreed that “the concept of the Rapture is not to be taken literally.” Furthermore, 18 percent selected a post-Tribulation paradigm, with smaller proportions for mid-Tribulation (4 percent), pre-wrath (4 percent), preterist ideals (1 percent), and none of the options presented (8 percent).

From the book, The Armageddon Code: One Journalist's Quest for End-Times Answers
by Billy Hallowell, page 171 (2016). A poll was commissioned through LifeWay Research, asking one thousand senior pastors, ministers, and priests—all Protestants who self-identified as either Evangelical, mainline, or “neither”—across America to tell us what they believe.